# Blazor Components in Razor Pages

Tags: blazor

We have a basic razor page app.  We would like to add Blazor components.  We have no problem getting this to work via replicating the steps in the 04/16 Blazor Update video or using the Blazor documentation.  However, once we add the Blazor component to a Razor page, all of our asp-page links no longer work.  The url changes in the address bar, but we remain on the same page.  The startup file is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    });

        services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();

        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
         });
    }
```

If some one can point me to a multi page tutorial with Razor Pages and Blazor Components, I’m sure we can figure this out! Thanks in advance!

The blazor components works fine.

```
<a asp-page="./Index">Home</a><br /> 
<div id="Counter"> @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>()) 
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js">
</script> 
</div>
```

The microsoft docs state - Integrate components into Razor Pages and MVC apps Use components with existing Razor Pages and MVC apps. There's no need to rewrite existing pages or views to use Razor components. When the page or view is rendered, components are prerendered† at the same time. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I think you will have to show what "add the Blazor component to a Razor page" actually means. Create a mockup when you can't post the real code (but make sure it compiles before posting it).

Comment: Yes, Blazor components are able to go inside of Razor pages.  See the snippet below.  The problem we are having is the asp-page links stop working.  The blazor components works fine.  <a asp-page="./Index">Home</a><br />

<div id="Counter">
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>())


    <script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

</div>

Comment: Integrate components into Razor Pages and MVC apps
Use components with existing Razor Pages and MVC apps. There's no need to rewrite existing pages or views to use Razor components. When the page or view is rendered, components are prerendered† at the same time. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I can confirm your symptoms. As soon as a Blazor component is called, the SignalR Hub takes over and the routing becomes Blazor''s. That's why I doubted this was a supported mode.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, prerendering in Blazor server-side is made possible by the html helper RenderComponentAsync which is used in Razor Pages. I'm not aware of another way to enable prerendering. And weather you wish to embed a single Razor Component or a whole app you have got to use the  html helper RenderComponentAsync method.

Comment: Correct and that is why i am alreaddy using -  @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>())  - See snippet above.   The rendering of the component works fine.   The other links on the page is what is broken.  Somewhere the navigation to other pages is being prevented.  I have changed the Startup file in every way I can imagine. Repo can be found at github.com/CarrotSolutions/WebApplication1.git

Comment: @Issac, Yes, the (pre)rendering works fine. But what doesn't seem to work is switching or co-operation between 2 routing mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opened this issue - https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9834.  Turns out, this was a bug that needed to be resolved by the Blazor team.  You will also want to take a look at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/10062.  To resolve immediately, do a pull request when this issue is closed or wait till the next preview release.

Answer (score 4):

In order to embed Razor Components in your Razor Pages you can do the following:

1. Add a folder named Components to your app
   1.1 Create a component named App.razor which should contain:
    
   `<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(MvcSandbox.Startup).Assembly" />`
2. Create a folder named Pages (Under the Components folder)
3. Place your Counter.razor file in this folder. This folder may  contain more Razor Components.
4. Add a _ViewImports.cshtml in the Pages folder. It should contain:

```
    @using WebApplication1.Components.Shared
    @layout MainLayout
```

5. Create a folder named Shared in your Components folder. This folder should contain two files: MainLayout.razor and NavMenu.razor.
   Just copy these files from a Blazor app.
6. Add a _ViewImports.cshtml file in the **Components** folder
   This file should contain: @namespace WebApplication1.Components

What actually we did here is creating a Blazor app, that would be prerendered and executed in your MVC or Razor Pages.

### How to use it:

1. In your application Pages folder (**WebApplication1.Pages**) add two files: Components.cshtml and Components.cshtml.cs

1.1 Components.cshtml may contain:

```
 @page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.ComponentsModel
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>WebApplication1- Components</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<WebApplication1.Components.App>())</app>

    <script src="_framework/components.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

1.2 Components.cshtml.cs should contain something like:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class ComponentsModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

That is all. If this does not work, the issue may be related to configuration faults in the Startup class.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Great try.  In fact, i performed your steps with the same result I'm already getting.  Adding the component works just fine.  Blazor features work.   However, the links off the page remain broken.  The address bar updates but there is no page navigation.  Just sits on the same page.

Comment: Repo can be found at github.com/CarrotSolutions/WebApplication1.git

Comment: What links are broken ? Could you provide an example and produce the steps you take, which result in the address bar updated, but no navigation is triggered ?

Comment: I can replicate this scenario in any boilerplate MVC or Razor Page default template.  Link to page with as Blazor component and all of the other page links will no longer function.  You can even replicate the same situation using the boilerplate template app for a Blazor Server Side app and linking to any mvc view or razor page.  This has to be a Startup issue. Removing
endpoints.MapBlazorHub(); will allow the links to work again but obviously that breaks the Blazor component.

Comment: Yes, as my code should be perfectly sound, I also thought of the startup configuration as the culprit. Go to github and either delete or edit the issue you posted there, and produce a new one wherein you report of a bug. Your current issue will not yield any response from the Blazor team as you are asking for help, but if you report of a bug, it will be treated differently.

Comment: Was there supposed to be some code after this point "Add a folder named Components to your app 1.1 Create a component named App.razor which should contain:"?  Could you add what the App.razor file should comprise of?

Comment: Blazor requires that your (Page) attributes have a name - its worth changing the @Page on your pages to include its route.. @Page(“/“) etc..

Comment: It is called directive, not attribute. Anyhow, Components.cshtml is a Razor Pages file, not a Blazor file, and no route template is to be provided...