# 404 Not found for blazor.webassembly.js in Blazor Web assembly app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I created a new "hosted" Blazor web assembly Razor class library and referenced it from a traditional .NET 5.0 MVC app.

The Razor class library components render just fine, however, the blazor client JS file is getting a 404 not found.  This is wasm and not server side.  I am attempting to pre-render components in a traditional ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC app.  I followed a few tutorials so I am not sure what I may be missing here. Here is the message in the browser:

```
404 - Not Found - https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js
```

Comment: Post your startup.cs you probably miss a middleware

Comment: As per @aguafrommars - try creating a blank ASP.NET-core-hosted Blazor WASM application, then compare the ASP.NET Core startup to see if you're missing something

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue now

Comment: Yes, I did, had to do with the ordering in the startup.cs file.  I used a "hosted blazor wasm" project and had to use an /wwwroot/index.html file and then call the UseBlazorFrameworkFiles() etc

Comment: Since this question is getting quite some views and votes, and the problem seems to be reproducable, would you mind to add the necessary code to your question needed to reproduce the problem? Then we could re-open, and you may write a self-answer (or someone else supplies one). :)

Comment: you should definitely put a detailed explanation of how resolved the problem. As @janw said, this problem seems to be frequent.

Comment: @Abdelhakim If you have a [mre], feel free to suggest an edit. I am happy to validate that and vote to reopen, if it does make the question complete. It suffices to state the steps that are needed to reproduce, and provide the code of Startup.cs. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem locally, so a minimal example would really help.

Comment: @jawn this is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870758/blazor-hosted-template-project-not-working-after-publishing-the-app) I asked earlier and it has all the details of the issue I had (Look in the comments of the accepted answer). Long story short, I create a new blazorwasm hosted template project. When I publish it to the default output folder (/bin/Release/net5.0/publish) it doesn't work because it misses blazor.webassembly.js file. But when I specify explicitely the output folder (dotnet publish --output ./out) every thing works fine. This is weird.

Comment: @Abdelhakim - I would have posted an answer, but the question was closed.  TBH - I don't have the time to try and get a quesiton re-opened etc.  I think sometimes questions are closed prematurely/arbitrarily and its unfortunate.  This is a *very* common problem with Blazor.  My startup is a HUGE file, that calls other files and its impossible to post a code sample.  If you want to share your code here, I'll post the sample, etc.

Comment: Had a similiar problem and found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088302/blazor-server-js-file-not-found

Comment: This is a *frequent* problem with multiple causes. It *can* appear in applications that worked fine for months

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue with the freshly release .net 6 and trying to upgrade from 3.1. I have yet to find my fix, as it seems to be a multi factored issue. I will follow other links in the comments here, hopefully it will lead to a solution.